# Lifecycle events on ReactCSSTransitionGroup's component?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to get notified of transition lifecycle events on a ReactCSSTransitionGroup's **parent** component? For example, if I have the following:

```
<ReactCSSTransitionGroup
    transitionName={transitionNames}
    transitionEnterTimeout={250}
    transitionLeaveTimeout={250}
    component={MyParent}>
      ...
</ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
```

I'd like `MyParent` to accept either lifecycle events, or an `isTransitioning`-like prop, so that I can (for example) render a different className based on whether a transition is happening or not.. something along the lines of

```
const MyParent = (props) => {
    if (props.isTransitioning) { // or something
        return <div className="animating" { ... props } />
    } else {
        return <div { ... props } />
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work? Can I know if a ReactCSSTransitionGroup is currently transitioning? All I can see is that the lifecycle events are fired on the **child** components entering or leaving the group, and not on the container component itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about passing `Parent` component to the `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`.
I would recommend another approach: simply wrap `<MyComponent />` with `<ParentComponent />` and setup callback props in `<MyComponent />` like so:

Link to the plunkr example -> https://plnkr.co/edit/hSRpiVIVQkZlYjyh2SuD?p=preview

Short explanation:
Each item in the list has CSS-class `.item`

```
.item {
  transition: opacity 250ms ease-in;
}
```

Once animation for the `.item` completed React (starting from v15) will fire the `onTransitionEnd` callback and will pass this information to the parent component.

And I've added callback `onBeforeItemTransition` to tell the `<Parent />` component, that something gonna happen soon, the transition should start.

```js
var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;

var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
    render() {
      return <MyComponent
      onItemTransitionEnd={(item) => {
        console.log('Transition end for item', item);
      }} />
    }
});

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      items: ['Item #0']
    }
  },
  
  getDefaultProps() {
    return {
      // We need to call this before we are starting animate items
      onBeforeItemTransition: function() {
        console.log('Transition started!');
      },
      // This should be called after ctra
      onItemTransitionEnd: function() {
      }
    }
  },
  
  addItem() {
    var newItems =
      this.state.items.concat(['Item #' + (this.state.items.length)]);
    this.setState({items: newItems});
    this.props.onBeforeItemTransition();
  },
  
  render() {
    
    var items = this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
      return <div className="item" key={item} onTransitionEnd={this.props.onItemTransitionEnd.bind(this, item)}>
        {item}
      </div>
    });
    
    return <div>
    <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add item</button>
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup
     transitionName="example" 
     transitionEnterTimeout={250} 
     transitionLeaveTimeout={250}>
      {items}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>

    </div>
  }
  
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <div>
    <h1>Rendered from script.jsx!</h1>
    <ParentComponent />
  </div>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```